Why are there no bounties on CL?
I just noticed this. I find that interesting. Is it because we have a smaller amount of users than other stacksites? or for some other reason?

My guess is that the 99% answer rate means we don't need to offer bounties.

I see. Thanks a lot @donkirkby
